# testmysql.php not working on wamp server after changing the port to 8080

Tags: wampserver

I just installed wampserver on windows 8 and I couldn't make it work, after reading a littler bit I was able to make it work changing the port form 80 to 8080.
now am trying to test it using the default file testmysql.php
like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost:8080','silv','123');
```

but now am getting the following error messages

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\testmysql.php on line 2
```

/

```
arning: mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Error while reading greeting packet. PID=4848 in C:\wamp\www\testmysql.php on line 2
```

/

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\testmysql.php on line 2
```

/

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\testmysql.php on line 2
```

any ideas what I may be doing wrong? is it the name of the host what the problem really is?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The port number for the MySQL server is not 8080 by default. In most cases it is either 3306 or 8889 by default. You should be able to see this in your WAMP server settings.